# JOptionPane.showInputDialog same style with the rest of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swing, dialog, joptionpane

So I'm trying to get the Dialog have the same style as the rest of the Eclipse.
This input is triggered when a button on a menu is pressed.
Here is my code right now , but the Dialog looks the same with **null** instead of **(Component) win** as parameter.

```java
    // JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Something");
    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    while (b != true) {
         userInput = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog((Component) win, "Entersomething", "GDB Server Connection Port:", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null,null,2345);
            if (userInput != null && userInput.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                b = true; }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component) win, "Please enter valid input","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
    return userInput ;
```

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT rather than Swing. I think you are probably getting null for the workbench window because it is certainly not a Component. Is this in an Eclipse plugin or is it a standalone Java program?

Comment: It's in a custom Eclipse plugin.

Comment: You will have to use SWT, JFace and Eclipse dialogs to make it look like the rest of Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LookAndFeel to have same style in whole application instead:

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

EDIT:

Have a look at this then:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DialogExamples.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html

Comment: It did help out as it changed the UI style, but what I want is have the same style like the Dialogs in the swt .